# Setting up VS Code for Android SDL2 Development

Tags: android, c, visual-studio-code, sdl-2

I'm working on deploying SDL2 apps to android, but I'm having trouble getting intellisense working on VS Code, with Microsoft's C/C++ extension pack (which provides C/C++ support, themes, and CMake support). I'm running Linux with all requirements installed.

I followed the instructions on https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/Android#simple_builds which creates a sample project in the `build` directory:

```
solaire@Bell ~/D/S/b/org.libsdl.testgles> pwd
/home/solaire/Downloads/SDL2-2.28.4/build/org.libsdl.testgles
solaire@Bell ~/D/S/b/org.libsdl.testgles> tree app/jni
app/jni
├── Android.mk
├── Application.mk
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── SDL
│   ├── Android.mk
│   ├── include -> /home/solaire/Downloads/SDL2-2.28.4/include
│   └── src -> /home/solaire/Downloads/SDL2-2.28.4/src
└── src
    ├── Android.mk
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── testgles.c
```

To try to get the project open and intellisense functional, after building the project and verifying that it deploys to my tablet, I opened subfolder `build/org.libsdl.testgles` in VS Code.

It prompted me to select a CMakeLists.txt, and I just took the one in `app/jni` because that referenced the `SDL` and `src` subdirectories.

Then, I opened up the main source file `app/jni/src/testgles.c`. I saw an `__ANDROID__` flag, and since I'm deploying to that target I opened `Edit C/C++ Configurations` and added `__ANDROID__`  to the list of defines.

I noticed `testgles.c` couldn't find an included `SDL_opengles.h`, so I added that header's containing folder "${workspaceFolder}/app/jni/SDL/include/**" to my include path, which fixed that issue.

But that header referenced some more headers that VS code couldn't find:

```
#include <GLES/gl.h>
#include <GLES/glext.h>
```

And I didn't see those headers anywhere in the SDL2-2.28.4 folder.

Here is the `c_cpp_properties.json` I have so far:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/app/jni/SDL/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": ["__ANDROID__"],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Could I get some help getting this working? I'm not sure if I'm on the right track with this or if people generally just use a different editor and rely on tags in this situation.